# Benefit of DiffList

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#reader) demonstrates the DiffList concept:

```
*Main Control.Monad.Writer> let f = \xs -> "dog" ++ ("meat" ++ xs)
*Main Control.Monad.Writer> f "foo"
"dogmeatfoo"
```

Is the primary benefit of the `DiffList` that the list gets constructed from left to right?

Comment: [Pretty much, yeah](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list), in that diff lists are more efficient for prepending values, and in certain circumstances that can give you quite the performance boost.

Comment: To be more specific, concatenation of normal lists is O(n) in its first argument; for difflists this is not the case.

There are often better alternatives to DiffLists for many use cases, however; see Data.Sequence for an example.

Comment: @MarkWhitfield: the big problem with `Data.Sequence` is that it has very high constant factors relative to nearly every other commonly-used data structure.  The big advantage it has over `DiffList` is that you can view it directly, whereas a `DiffList` must be converted to a regular list first (the 'Reflection Without Remorse' paper covers this well).  If you don't need to view/deconstruct the list until it's fully created, `DiffList` will outperform `Data.Sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

The `DList` package lists some of the asymptotics: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.5/docs/Data-DList.html

You'll note lots of things only take O(1), including `cons`, `snoc`, and `append`. However, note that inspecting the list needs to force lots of operations each time, so if you are doing more inspecting than construction, or interleaving the two, the `DList` approach won't necessarily be a win.